# cross-site scripting protection measures

Tags: xss

I would like to know the commonly used cross-site scripting (XSS) client and server side protection measures? I know about OWASP's general guidelines available at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet but I need to know client/server side tools?

Regards

ashar